# typescript - transparently wrap class constructor, with type signature retained

Tags: typescript

I want to wrap the constructor of `BaseClass`, which comes from a library I can't change, in order to add a prefix to the `name` field passed to the constructor.

I'd like my wrapper to be as agnostic of types as possible. The only thing it really needs to know is that the first argument passed to the constructor contains that string `name` property. The `SubClass` should have the same type signature as the `BaseClass`.

**The following code doesn't quite work**

The linter complains that the `config` passed to `super` is of type `Param0<string>` not `Param0<T>`, but it doesn't like it when I use `ConstructorParameters<typeof BaseClass<T>>[0]` (i.e. with the extra `<T>`).

```
type Param0<T extends string> = { name: string, t_val: T };

class BaseClass<T extends string>{
  constructor(config: Param0<T>) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}

class SubClass<T extends string> extends BaseClass<T> {
  constructor(config: ConstructorParameters<typeof BaseClass>[0]) {
    config.name = "special_prefix_" + config.name;
    super(config);
  }
}
```

**Bonus**

I've no idea if this would make any sense, but it would nice if there was some sort of syntax to avoid explicitly include the `<T extends string>` bit. Something like this maybe...:

```
class SubClass<...Generics extends GenericsOf<BaseClass>>
      extends BaseClass<...Generics>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to opt-out from using `ConstructorParameters` and copy-paste the constructor signature.

```
class SubClass<T extends string> extends BaseClass<T> {
  constructor(config: Param0<T>) {
    config.name = "special_prefix_" + config.name;
    super(config);
  }
}
```

Because if you do this:

```
config: ConstructorParameters<typeof BaseClass>[0]
```

`BaseClass` is not saturated with `T` yet, so TypeScript doesn't know what `T` should be. It will not allow you to substitute anything as `T`, since it cannot tell what `T` is.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean about TS not being able to resolve `T` automatically - I'm not clear if that's a limitation of the way TS is implemented or if it logically has to be that way. At any rate, I've adopted your approach as it's certainly a pragmatic solution (it did occur to me earlier but I thought I might have been missing something nicer).